# Sign a message with existing GPG key

Tags: solidity

I am writing a proof of concept smart contract that has to take a message, sign it with private GPG key and return signed message. For the sake of the test lets assume that private GPG key is stored in the local variable of the function.

What would be my approach? The whole operation should be done in solidity.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, your approach is wrong. Having the private key stored in the smart contract makes it public to anyone, as any variable can be retrieved from the blockchain. Thus, any signature would be useless because anyone can generate one based on the private key (publicly available) stored in the smart contract.

What you should do is generate a ECDSA private key (secp256k1), sign a message offchain and verify the signature on the smart contract.

For your reference check the [following](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.19/solidity-by-example.html#creating-and-verifying-signatures) guide on how to create and verify signatures in Solidity.

Comment: Thank you.  I will look into that